# numpy.core._exceptions.MemoryError: Unable to allocate 10.3 GiB for an array with shape (138494, 10000) and data type float64

Tags: python, numpy, out-of-memory, dtype

```
def train(self):
        self.P = np.random.rand(self.nr_users, self.K)/self.K
        self.Q = np.random.rand(self.nr_events, self.K)/self.K
        self.b_u = np.zeros(self.nr_users, dtype='uint8')
        self.b_m = np.zeros(self.nr_events, dtype='uint8')
        self.b = np.uint8(np.mean(self.R[np.where(self.R != 0)]))
```

numpy.core._exceptions.MemoryError: Unable to allocate 10.3 GiB for an array with shape (138494, 10000) and data type float64

Unable to get rid of this error. Tried the .astype=('uint8') does not work. My python is running on 64-bit so wondering why I am facing this issue.
How do I add dtype='uint8' in a np.random.rand variable?_

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.randint.html